# Creating link to list item in folder

Tags: 2010, list, workflow, item, designer

I have a SP2010 site with a list of clients, generated by them filling out an online form. I have created a workflow that, When a new list item is created, creates a corresponding folder in a separate document library.

What I would like to do is augment the workflow so that it adds a link to the original list item (form) in the newly created folder. Is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

In your target document library you can add the "Link to a Document" content type and from your workflow, create "Link to a document" type item with the link to your custom list item like https://webappname/sites/sitename/Lists/listname/DispForm.aspx?ID=1

*Note: You can get the current item URL in workflow through workflow context > Current Item URL.*

When a user clicks on the "Link to a document" item in the folder, they will be redirected to the custom list item display form.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks Rajesh. I've created the "Link to a a Document" content type in the target library but I'm not sure what you mean when you say to create a "Link to a document" type item in my workflow. Could you explain a little further please?

Comment: In your workflow after you create a folder, create an item (Content type should be "link to document") inside that folder.

Comment: Sorry to be dumb - I'm trying this but it returns an error ("The workflow could not create the list item. Make sure the list exists and the user has permissions to add items to the list." I'm pretty sure I do have the necessary permissions to add items to the list).  I've taken a screenshot of the workflow in SPD but I don't know how to insert it into this comment.

Comment: But basically, I've set "Content Type ID" to "Link to a Document" and "Path and Name" to "[%Workflow Context:CurrentItemURL%]"

Comment: I'm wondering now if I do have the right permissions - I'll check with the site admin when I get back to work on Monday